# looping through results and writing lines to a file

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to loop through a list of lines and write the lines to a file.

```yaml
- command: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - ls 
    - df -h
  register: files
- lineinfile:
    line: "{{ item.stdout }}"
    path: /home/ubuntu/log/list.log
    create: yes
  loop: "{{ files.results | flatten }}"
  loop_control:
     label: item.stdout
```

But I am seeing below error:

> 'PermissionError' object is not subscriptable

I modified code as per @toydarian suggestion and working fine. if I have multiple tasks, I have changed as follows:

```yaml
- command: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - "ls" 
    - "df -h"
  register: files

- command: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - "ls -lrt" 
    - "du -h"
  register: files1      

- lineinfile:
    line: "{{ item.stdout }}"
    path: /home/ubuntu/log/list.log
    create: yes
  loop: 
    - "{{ files.results }}"
    - "{{ files1.results }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

I can see below error:

> "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a small error in your loop. You can loop over `files.results` and then use `{{ item.stdout }}` as `line`:

```yaml
  - command: "{{ item }}"
    loop:
      - "ls" 
      - "df -h"
    register: files

  - command: "{{ item }}"
    loop:
      - "ls -lrt" 
      - "du -h"
    register: files1
  
  - lineinfile:
      line: "{{ item.stdout }}"
      path: /home/ubuntu/log/list.log
      create: yes
    loop: "{{ files.results + files1.results }}"
```

Check the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop) on registering variables with a loop.

Note:
Depending on what you want to do, you might want to consider using ansible modules (e.g. [find](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html)) instead of running things in `command` or `shell` tasks.

Comment: if I have one more task like `- command: "{{item}}" loop: - "ls -lrt" - "du -h" register: files1` how can place `fiels1 in lineinfile`

Comment: you can just add another `lineinfile` task with the same file. It will append the additional lines at the end.

Comment: @BinduG you can edit your question, if the answer is not clear enough, so I can understand your problem better

Comment: @BinduG let me know if you need more assistance

Comment: Thanks a lot @toydarian, everything is working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234580/discussion-between-bindu-g-and-toydarian).